# Elementwise Power in IT++

Tags: c++, exponential, elementwise-operations

I was wondering if it was possible to do element wise power in it++. I have not seen a builtin function, and if I overlooked it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Connect the it++ to your power socket? Element-wise, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

This /http://itpp.sourceforge.net/devel/group__logexpfunc.html

Has all the various exponential functions.  I'm sure what you need can be found here